# How to convert '1,2' into a tuple (1,2) in python?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

INPUT: '1,2' which is a string.

OUTPUT: (1,2) which is a tuple.

How to accomplish that? Is there an easy way?

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Looked into the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html), perhaps?

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval('1,2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def Convert(s):
    p = s.split(",")
    return (int(p[0]), int(p[1]))
```

Comment: input is string not x, y.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = '1,2'
print tuple(map(int,a.split(',')))
```

Comment: @Petar: Thanks for mentioning. Made an change. It returns int now

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '1,2'
s_tuple = tuple(map(int, s.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using map:

```
a = '1,2'
print tuple(int(x) for x in list(a.split(',')))
```